# Circle between parabolas

Tags: geometry

The problem I am working is to find the equation of the circle lying between two parabolas and tangent to both parabolas as shown in the figure.  I have tried to solve this problem using Mathematica by equating the equations of the parabolas with the circle, and the derivative of these equations, but get bogged down in the size of intermediate steps. One help I have found is to equate dx/dy of the equations instead of dy/dz.  This leads to a cubic equation instead of a quartic equation as an intermediate step.

[image]

Comment: There are infinitely many circles that are tangent to both parabolas $y=x^2$ and $y = x^2 + 1$ and between the curves.... Either you need a constraint, or solve this problem to get some sort of parametrized answer

Comment: Is the radius $r$ given?

Answer (score 0):

Let the center of the circle be in $(x_0,y_0)$ and its radius $r$. Suppose it intersects the first parabola at $(u,u^2)$ and the second at $(v,v^2+1)$. We should convince ourselves first that $u=v=x_0=0$ is the only solution with $u$ or $v$ equals $0$.

Then, lets suppose that $x_0 \neq 0$. In this case, the line that pass through $(u,u^2)$ and is normal to the parabola at this point is $y_1 = u^2- \frac{x-u}{2u}$, and for the second parabola is $y_2 = v^2+1 - \frac{x-v}{2v}$. These lines meet in $(x_0,y_0)$, so:

$$\frac{x_0-u}{2u} =  u^2- y_0$$
$$\frac{x_0-v}{2v} = v^2+1 - y_0$$

And also, because the points of contact are also points in the circle, we have

$$(u-x_0)^2 + (u^2-y_0)^2 = r^2$$

$$(v-x_0)^2 + ((v+1)^2-y_0)^2 = r^2$$

So:

$$(u-x_0)^2 \left(1 + \frac{1}{4u^2}\right) = r^2$$
$$(v-x_0)^2\left(1+\frac{1}{4v^2}\right)=r^2$$

We can work with this 4 equations and solve for any of the variables, but we need some parameter. Those are enough for Mathematica or other software to compute the locci of the centers and other interesting features

Comment: I want to choose a parameter from the circle equation unknowns: xc, yc, and r in my original question.  (xc = x0 and yc = y0 using your terminology.)  So, let xc be a parameter and then find the equations of yc = f(xc) and r = g(xc).  As I stated in the original question, this has led me to very large intermediate results. For example, using the Mathematica expression Solve[{y==x^2 && (x-xc)^2 + (y-yc)^1==r^2} , x,y] results in well over 100 term expressions for x and y.  Then, we must work with the equations for dx/dy  for the circle and parabola and continue to eliminate variables.